# Slick Carousel (Next/Prev Button Placement)

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Slick Carousel (Next/Prev Button Placement)

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
        <div class="item red"></div>
        <div class="item orange"></div>
        <div class="item green"></div>
        <div class="item blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>

$('#carousel').slick({
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 3
});
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/y86g8916/)

Everything is working fine , but i wanted to ask is that how do i make the Next Previous button are placed in the box instead of outside (see example below)

What I wanted:
The Button is on the image (like the example below) - DONE + a button with opacity when user hover

Example :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try adding ```.slick-next,
.slick-prev {
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 0;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 0;
}```

to your CSS and see if that solves your issue. The explanation is that slick defaults to `left: -25px` for previous and `right: -25px` for next. You need to reset those. Once you do that, you also need to give them `z-index: 1` so that the show up on top of the sliders. The last bit is that if you want the buttons to show at the very bottom, you'll need to rest the `top` property and add `bottom: 0`

Comment: The outside position is default, to change that edit those absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: @volt sorry for the late reply , as implement the codes , the button placement are wrong (when my screen is bigger/smaller)

Comment: @greenboxgoolu You're adding fixed widths to both `.container` and `.carousel`. If you want them to be responsive, you should give them both `max-width: 100%;` as well. Also, you have this in your example: `.container {margin-left: 20px;}`. If you want to keep the spacing, you should use `.container {
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}` instead so that it's factored in its width calculation.

Answer (score 2):

you should add first this style

## First-Step

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 35px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

## Second-Step

```
.slick-prev {
    left: 30px;
   
}
```

## Third-Step

```
.slick-next {
    right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Hi , sorry for the late reply , is there any place i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Everybody else already gave you the right answer, but since there seems to be something wrong with JS Fiddle right now, I'll throw the code in a snippet for you.

Also, due to the way these snippets include the CSS, the Slick styles were overwriting the ones added here. So I had to make them `!important`.

```js
$('#carousel').slick({
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 3
});
```

```css
.slick-prev::before, .slick-next::before { color: black; }

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item, .content { height: 200px !important; }

.red    { background: red; }
.orange { background: orange; }
.green  { background: green; }
.blue   { background: blue; }

.carousel-2 .item { margin-right: 15px; }

.carousel-3 .item .content { margin-right: 15px; }

/* Not CSS for carousel, but CSS to get the look I want Slick to manage automatically for me. */
.carousel-4 .item {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 15px;
   width: 180px;
}
.carousel-4 .item:nth-child(3) { margin-right: 0; }

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
.slick-next {
    right: 0 !important;
}
.slick-prev {
    left: 0 !important;
}

.slick-prev:hover, .slick-next:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<!-- Standard carousel where Slick calculated the best widths to fit. -->
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
        <div class="item red"></div>
        <div class="item orange"></div>
        <div class="item green"></div>
        <div class="item blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sketch, add the following CSS classes:

```
.slick-prev {
  left: 10px;
  top: 180px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 10px;
  top: 180px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

For the opacity on hover add:

```
.slick-prev:hover, .slick-next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Somehow the JSfiddle is not saving for me, I'll try again in a bit

Answer (score 1):

```
.container .slick-arrow {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 100;
   opacity: 0;
}
.container .slick-arrow:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
.container .slick-prev {
   left: 0;
}
.container .slick-next {
   right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your css. You can change the `0` for bottom, right and left to whatever offset you'd like.

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    top:auto;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.slick-next {
    right: 0;
}
.slick-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.slick-prev:hover, .slick-next:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

If you want to remove the extra space where the buttons used to be then change `.container` to the this:

```
.container { width: 570px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tgv30he/1/)

adding below styling to css will move arrows to location in your image.

```
/* to align arrow at bottom */

.slick-prev{
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.slick-next{
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

if you want arrow to be opaced by default and visible on hover add below style.

```
/* to add opacity on default and remove it on hover */

.slick-prev,
.slick-next{
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-next:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```